# How to add gradle file to flutter project in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I have an issue with gradle file. When I try to run my flutter project -for the first time ever- the operation gets stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...".

I found that my interent is slow so I can't download the gradle.zip file. So I downloaded the file out of vscode. but I couldn't link the file to the project or flutter environment, given that I have added the path of the gradle binary file to the system variables.

I type "flutter run -v" and I think the vscode trying to download gradle.zip file even though that I have it on my laptop

<<<I DON'T HAVE ANDROID STUDIO BUT I HAVE INSTALLED ANDROID SDK>>>

Added gradle bin to environment variables
Run "gradle -v" and got "Gradle 8.1.1"
Don't know what to do else

Comment: You should install Android Studio, while open your peoject in Android Studio. It auto import (or add supported files) all the required files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.